# Factoring 2048 bit number is easy?

Tags: rsa, prime-numbers, factoring

my PC found a factor for (2^2048)-1 in under a second...so does that make RSA-2048 less secure right? i used prime 95. and actually i am kinda curious how it found a factor so fast? i can even factor 2^131072 in less than 5 minutes..?
[image]

Comment: Please learn to write in $\LaTeX$/MathJax.

Comment: I can factor $2^{131072}$ in my head in rather less than 5 minutes, if I don't have to explicitly list every prime factor...

Comment: Are you also [Ömer Enes Özmen](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/73458/%c3%96mer-enes-%c3%96zmen). If so, can merge your accounts.

Answer (score 8):

> my PC found a factor for (2^2048)-1 in under a second...so does that make RSA-2048 less secure right?

**No.  Factoring numbers with special forms like that is easy.**

You have a Mersenne number, $n = 2^e - 1$, whose exponent $e = 2048$ is composite.  Whenever $e = u v$, we have $2^u - 1 \mid (2^u)^v - 1 = 2^e - 1$, since in general $x - 1 \mid x^k - 1$.  (Proof: Write out $(x - 1)(x^{k - 1} + x^{k - 2} + \dotsb + x + 1)$.)  So, for example, the following are all obviously factors of $2^{2048} - 1$:

- $2^2 - 1 = 3$
- $2^4 - 1 = 15 = 3\cdot 5$
- $2^8 - 1 = 255 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 17$
- $2^{16} - 1 = 65535 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 17\cdot 257$
- $2^{32} - 1 = 4294967295 = 3\cdot 5\cdot 17\cdot 257\cdot 65537$

Indeed, in general, for $x^{2k} - 1$, we have $\bigl((x^k)^2 - 1\bigr)/(x^k - 1) = x^k + 1$, so we can reduce $2^{2048} - 1 = 2^{2^{10}} - 1$ to a product of Fermat numbers, which are numbers of the form $2^{2^t} + 1$:

\begin{align*}
  2^{2048} - 1
    &= (2^{1024} + 1) (2^{1024} - 1) \\
    &= (2^{1024} + 1) (2^{512} + 1) (2^{512} - 1) \\
    &\vdots \\
    &= (2^{1024} + 1) (2^{512} + 1) \dotsm (2^2 + 1) (2^1 + 1).
\end{align*}

The only prime Fermat numbers known are 3, 5, 17, 257, and 65537; the remaining factors here are known to be composite.

The ninth Fermat number, $2^{2^9} + 1 = 2^{512} + 1$, was factored in 1990 using the special number field sieve (SNFS), and the tenth, $2^{2^{10}} + 1 = 2^{1024} + 1$, was factored in 1995 using the elliptic curve method (ECM), according to [Richard Brent's retrospective](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-225/S0025-5718-99-00992-8/S0025-5718-99-00992-8.pdf).  I don't know what algorithm your software uses, but there are enough small factors that it is entirely plausible for software on a laptop today to identify most of them—the number it printed has the two smallest factors of $F_{10} = 2^{1024} + 1$, namely 45 592 577 and 6 487 031 809; the smallest factor of $F_9 = 2^{512} + 1$, namely 2 424 833; and the smallest factor of $F_6 = 2^{64} + 1$, namely 274 177.

**In contrast, when $n$ is a product of two *uniform random* 1024-bit prime numbers, or nearly uniform random, then it's hard.**

Comment: i'm using Prime95, wich is specifically designed for factoring mersenne primes